# Why are immutable objects 'more efficient' for generational GC?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, immutability

"Young GC becomes inefficient if we have tenured objects referring to younger generations" is quoted as one of the reasons to favor immutable objects.

- What exactly happens when the collector comes across such an object in the old generation?
- Why should it be any more cumbersome than collecting an older object referring to an object in the young generation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To collect the Eden space (of the young gen.) any live objects are copied from the Eden space to one of the survivor spaces.  Objects already in a survivor space are copied from the 'from' space to the 'to' space unless they are old enough to be promoted to the old generation (in which case they are copied there).

All of this involves object relocation.  To do this safely any objects in the old generation that point to objects in the new generation (that are being relocated during a minor GC) must have those references updated.  The more objects that have references to objects being relocated, the more work the GC has to do during a minor GC.

If you use only immutable objects the number of objects that will contain pointers from the old gen. to the young gen. will be very small (most likely zero).  There are only two ways this could happen:

1. An object is promoted to the old gen. whilst an object it refers to
   is still in a survivor space.
2. An object is large enough to be allocated directly in the old gen. and refers to an object in the young gen.

To summarise the answer, by using immutable objects you're reducing the possible number of object references that the GC has to update during a minor collection, therefore improving its efficiency.

Comment: Why would references need to be updated ? Does copy from eden to survivor involve object recycling?

Comment: If object A refers to object B and object B is relocated (from Eden to survivor, survivor to survivor or survivor to old gen.) then the reference in object A must be updated. Once the region of memory previously occupied by object B is reused the reference in object A will be to something completely different.

Answer (score -1):

- What exactly happens when the collector comes across such an object in the old generation?How does it handle it?

Typical it can't, before the collector considers collecting objects in the older generation it promotes anything it could not reap in the younger generation so by the time the collectors considers if the parent object can be collected they are no longer in the younger generation.  I think they issue is what happens when it comes across the object in the younger generation, it has to skip it, and could skip it hundreds or thousands of times as it does the younger generation GCs before it has to do one on the older generation.

- Why should it be any more cumbersome than collecting a younger object referring to an object in the tenured generation?

Being referenced by an older generation object means it is effectively frozen in the young generation, being referenced by a younger generation object is no issue as the younger generations are all resolved before it starts collecting from the older generation.

I think as long as you are disciplined about de-referencing all your unused objects then it will not hurt your GC efficiency but that can be a lot of extra work in a big application.